# HTTPS redirect www to non www

Tags: nginx

I got 2 domains and its supposed to work from same directory. While redirecting from http with/without www works perfectly, https www to non www don't work. Here is my config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    return 301 https://domain1.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;
    return 301 https://domain2.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.domain1.com;
    return 301 https://domain1.com$request_uri;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.domain2.com;
    return 301 https://domain2.com$request_uri;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain1.com;
    root /var/www/domain1.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain2.com;
    root /var/www/domain1.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

Can you tell me what could be wrong with it? SSL certificate domain1.com have got inside certificates for all domains, include with/without WWW.

Comment: The `ssl_certificate` directives specifie the same certificate for all of your domains.

Comment: that's right, I got one certificate for all domains.

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone will face to same issue, removal of "ssl" abbreviate fixed it. So instead of listen 443 ssl; in 301 server blocks change to listen 443;